# Include resources in jar using Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, jar, proguard, android-resources

I build my library using gradle and distribute as a **jar** by extracting **classes.jar** from the resulted aar.

I need to add drawables to the jar to read dynamically by addeding a "drawables.zip" containing my drawables under "resources" directory. The full path: src/main/resources/drawables.zip.

[image]

My problem is that the **debug** classes.jar contains the resources, whereas the **release** classes.jar doesn't.

Debug jar: [image]

Release jar: [image]

My build types are as following:

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
        }
 }
```

As you can see, minify is enabled in release, so i figured that proguard removes the directory, but i was not able to find a proguard property to keep the directory.
I tried adding the following to proguard-rules.pro:

```
-keepdirectories src\main\resources\drawables.zip
-injars src\main\resources\drawables.zip
```

Which didn't help.

Comment: please add snippets where you tried `-keepdirectories` and `-injars` in your `proguard-rules.pro` file